# how to pass a tibble to caret::confusionmatrix()?

Tags: r, dplyr, r-caret, confusion-matrix, yardstick

Consider this simple example:

```
data_frame(truth = c(1,1,0,0),
           prediction = c(1,0,1,0),
           n_obs = c(100,10,90,50))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  truth prediction n_obs
  <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
1     1          1   100
2     1          0    10
3     0          1    90
4     0          0    50
```

I would like to pass this `tibble` to `caret::confusionMatrix` so that I have all the metrics I need at once (`accuracy`, `recall`, etc).

As you can see, the `tibble` contains all the information required to compute performance statistics. For instance, you can see that in the test dataset (not available here), there are 100 observations where the predicted label `1` matched the true label `1`. However, `90` observations with a predicted value of `1` were actually false positives.

I do not want to compute all the metrics by hand, and would like to resort to `caret::confusionMatrix()`

However, this has proven to be suprisingly difficult. Calling `confusionMatrix(.)` on the `tibble` above does not work. Is there any solution here?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Because you need other arguments to use `caret::confusionMatrix`

Comment: your table is not usable. How can you tell how many predictions you have as 1 and as 0? See what happens when you use 'xtabs(n_obs ~ . , df)'.

Comment: guys... the table gives you how many observations fall in each category. For instance, there are 100 observations in the testing dataset where the `predicted` value `1` match the `label` value `1`

Comment: In essence this table contains all the information we need to get confusionMatrix() working. but I was unable to do so. Perhaps by transforming into a `table` beforehand? (caret accepts that as an input). This problem arises because the table comes directly from Spark

Comment: using your logic truth and prediction are exactly the same, also you have 100 and 90 predictions of 1. a.k.a what xtabs shows. Your model achieves 100% accuracy?

Comment: I apologize there is a typo in the `tibble` thanks for catching that

Comment: @phiver question updated with more detail. thanks again!

Comment: @phiver `xtabs(n_obs ~ . , df)`works like a charm. do you mind posting this as an answer. happy to accept then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following. You have to set the positive class to 1 otherwise 0 will be taken as the positive class.

`confusionMatrix(xtabs(n_obs ~ prediction + truth , df), positive = "1")`

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          truth
prediction   0   1
         0  50  10
         1  90 100

               Accuracy : 0.6             
                 95% CI : (0.5364, 0.6612)
    No Information Rate : 0.56            
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.1128          

                  Kappa : 0.247           
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 2.789e-15       

            Sensitivity : 0.9091          
            Specificity : 0.3571          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.5263          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.8333          
             Prevalence : 0.4400          
         Detection Rate : 0.4000          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.7600          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.6331          

       'Positive' Class : 1
```

Comment: very efficient. `xtabs` a life saver here

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ, yes base functions still have their use :-)